# Spring Data Neo4j 5 update dynamic properties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, dynamic-properties, spring-data-neo4j-5

I have the following entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value {

    @Properties(prefix = "property", allowCast = true)
    private Map<String, Object> properties;

}
```

I have added the following properties:

```
Map<String, Object> properties1 = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("key1", "one");
properties.put("key2", "two");

value.setProperties(properties1);
```

Right now on the database level, I have the `Value` node with two properties:

```
property.key1 = "one"
property.key2 = "two"
```

Now, I'd like to update the properties for this `Value` node. In order to do this I have created other properties:

```
Map<String, Object> properties2 = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("key1", "three");
```

After updating the node on the database level I have the following properties:

```
property.key1 = "three"
property.key2 = "two"
```

As you may see, the following approach correctly updated the property with the `key1` but doesn't remove the property with the `key2`.

How to properly update the dynamic properties in order to remove all properties with the keys that are absent in the new `properties2` HashMap?

**UPDATED**

As suggested at the answer below, I use the following code inorder to reuse the same properties from the Value node:

```
Map<String, Object> oldProperties = value.getProperties();
Map<String, Object> newProperties = extractProperties(properties);

mergeMaps(newProperties, oldProperties);

protected void mergeMaps(Map<String, Object> sourceMap, Map<String, Object> destinationMap) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = destinationMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = sourceMap.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            iterator.remove();
        } else {
            entry.setValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

but it still doesn't work with the same result as previously - it still doesn't remove the properties from the Neo4j node by the removed keys. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard `Map.remove` method to remove an entry from the map:

```
properties.remove("key2");
```

Also, you should not be making new `Map` objects over and over again, just use the one `Map` and update it.

UPDATE: That didn't work. But, you can use a Cypher query to remove a property:

```
session.query("MATCH (v:Value) REMOVE v.`property.key2`", Collections.emptyMap());
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the code which tries to merge the existing Value properties instead of creating a new one. But it still doesn't with the same result.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No matter what I do, I cannot remove a property from a node. Even using Cypher from the browser isn't working for me: MATCH (v:Value) REMOVE v.key2 RETURN v;   still shows key2 property.

Comment: I was finally able to delete the property using a Cypher query. It needs backticks around the property name:  `session.query("MATCH (v:Value) REMOVE v.\`property.key2\`", Collections.emptyMap());`

Comment: Thanks! I'm also thinking to remove these properties via additional Cypher query but still wondering is it the only way to do it or it can be automatically managed by SDN/OGM and dynamic properties functionality out of the box?

Comment: From our testing, it seems to confirm that OGM doesn't let you remove properties. It might be worth submitting it to neo4j as a feature request/bug report.

Comment: Sorry, sorry for the late response. Thank you!

Comment: It's no problem. Thank you very much.